# Entity framework and Oracle Public database links

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, entity-framework

I've recently been looking into using EF in my .Net pages but I'm struggling a little when trying to access the public databases that are set up.

So for example in my Oracle SQL developer I would access a public database like this

```
SELECT name FROM users@publicserver
```

I'm trying to use this in the following way

```
Using myEntities As New TestEntities()
    Dim allNames = From name In myEntities.users@publicserver
                     Select name
    GridView1.DataSource = allNames
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Using
```

Obviously this doesn't work as my EF doesn't contain the public server table as I'm not sure how to even add this to the EF (if that makes sense?)

I'm interested to know if it is possible to achieve this and if not does anyone have any ideas on the best method of accessing this?

**EDIT**

Ideally I'd like to be able to use LINQ with my Public database links if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Synonyms?

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[MyTable] FOR [AnotherDatabase].dbo.[MyTable]
```

And then you could write:

```
SELECT name FROM MyTable
```

Synonyms work, but they are not automatically detected for reverse engineering, so you will need to manually edit the .edmx file to make them work. [Here is how to do it](http://forums.asp.net/t/1771938.aspx/1).

Another option is to go for the Code First approach, and use the [Table] annotation, and just plain write the name of the synonym instead of the name of a table

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've never tried synonyms before are these accessible via EF then?

Comment: They seem to work correctly, but sadly, they are not automatically detected, so you need to manually edit the .edmx file to make it work

Comment: Oh that's brilliant i'll have a look and see if I can get that working then - Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway for the EDMX to populate the columns automatically?

Comment: For a Synonym? No. You could of course create a table that is "similar" and reverse engineer from that...

Comment: I've just been trying to figure out how to add synonyms to and edmx and it seems quite difficult I haven't managed it as yet - will keep trying though

Comment: Maybe if you extend http://salardbcodegenerator.codeplex.com/ you could add the capability to do it automatically, but it sure doesn't seem trivial

Comment: As this does solve my problem I've awarded it the answer and bounty - but a lot of effort is needed to make it work. Thanks for the advice on this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just selecting the data from another database then create a view and include that in your list of tables and views.
If you want to update, insert or delete over a database then you need to think about a few issues:

- are the two databases connected with a fast reliable link? Slow links will slow your applications response time.  Impatient users have been known to keep clicking until something happens...
- what are the consequences if the transaction on the linked database fails?  Should the whole transaction fail or is it sufficient for the failure to be logged?
- when writing to a different database I prefer to use Oracle advanced queues so that the transaction on the initial database completes and the transaction on the linked database can be dealt with and logged separately.  This won't meet a requirement for instant synchronization but often the requirement is for consistency soon, not consistency immediately
- either way update, insert and delete actions on a database link are better dealt with in  a package which encapsulates the link and hides it from the Entity Framework.

Edit: if your connection is not as stable as you  would like then using an advanced queue makes even more sense.  See this somewhat [dated article](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_advanced_queueing.html) for the basics.  By using a queue you get these features:

- by putting your insert/delete/updates on the queue the actions in the application can complete without waiting for confirmation that the the secondary transaction on the linked database has succeeded.
- the queue is set up to keep track how many times a transaction between the databases has been attempted
- the potential complexity of the operation  does not need to be dealt with by application code.  You can let EF do what it does best: provide an interface to the database while your other requirement, link to another database, is taken care of by the database.

All of the CRUD operations can be encapsulated in a database package which EF can use.

You can use LINQ and Oracle without the entity framework if you use the [latest release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html) on an 11g database. This release is still squeaky new as of this date so you may want to look for other users opinions before adopting this on a production platform.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer -it's going to involve updates, deletes etc so a view wouldn't quite solve this. also the link is a bit hit and miss. So if I wasn't to use EF would I still be able to use LINQ with Oracle?